# Best (PostgreSQL?) Data Model and Processing for Incremental Entity Resolution/Record Linkage

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, data-modeling

I am tackling a problem I would like your opinion on.

We are trying to do a deterministic Entity Resolution/Record Linkage with simple equality comparison. Incrementally, on a stream events. And I am trying to figure out how to do it in PostgreSQL with scaling in mind.

Imagine you have a stream of events. For the sake of example let's stick to example of events from web tracking. Events might as follows (only leaving most important parts, not the whole payload):

```
1. EventID: 1, Cookie: A
2. EventID: 2, Cookie: B
3. EventID: 3, Cookie: A
4. EventID: 4, Cookie: B
```

As you can see, we have 2 attributes - EventID and Cookie so far. From this event stream, as a result we want to have some representation (data model) that describes that EventIDs 1 and 3 are connected to Cookie A and EventIDs 2 and 4 are connected to Cookie B. Simplest pseudo-representation (this is what I am struggling with, also processing) can look like this (curly brackets are sets):

```
EventIDs,Identifiers
{"1","3"},{"Cookie|A"}
{"2","4"},{"Cookie|B"}
```

Let's do one more round:

```
5. EventID: 5, Cookie: A, Email: a@example.com
6. EventID: 6, Cookie: B, Email: b@emample.com
```

After this round, the entity representation will look like this:

```
EventIDs,Identifiers
{"1","3","5"},{"Cookie|A","Email|a@example.com"}
{"2","4","6"},{"Cookie|B","Email|b@example.com"}
```

So far so good. One more event to setup grand finale:

```
7. EventID: 7, Cookie: A, Phone: 1234
```

Entities:

```
EventIDs,Identifiers
{"1","3","5","7"},{"Cookie|A","Email|a@example.com","Phone|1234"}
{"2","4","6"},{"Cookie|B","Email|b@example.com"}
```

And grand finale:

```
8. EventID: 8, Cookie: B, Phone: 1234
```

As you can see - with this new event we found that a new link and we NOW know that those two entities are connected:

```
EventIDs,Identifiers
{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"},{"Cookie|A","Cookie|B","Email|a@example.com","Email|b@example.com","Phone|1234"}
```

This is a problem statement: **Given the stream of events, where each event has its own unique ID and 1 to N identifiers of different types, how do we do the resolution (variation on transitive closure basically?) in PostgreSQL (or other tool? I am open to suggestion) so it scales to 1BN events and 100M entities (whichever comes first) with incremental processing?**

**What have we tried so far?**
Python - custom algorithm. Worked well, but is memory bound - we used Python Dictionaries to store entity ID and its identifiers, plus inverted dictionary to hold identifier and its entity ID for fast lookup (O(1) for lookup). As you can imagine, holding such dictionaries in memory consumes a lot of it - at 30M entities we are at 25GB of data. Not gonna scale.

PostgreSQL - I used basically the same table I described to hold entities. Then a trigger on insert to this table that looks up all candidate entities where EventID or EntityID is the same as we want insert, delete them from the entity table, merge the result with new row to be inserted and insert this new merged entity. Works well, does not scale - race conditions while merging entities.

Apache Spark - I converted the event stream into a graph where node is identifier (Phone, Email, ...) and edges are defined as "identifier appeared together with other identifier in the same event) and used GraphFrame's Connected Components algorithm. Works well, but it is a batch processing the whole history each run. But I want to it incremental.

If you are interested in the codes I used, feel free to ask. For the sake of this post and keeping it reasonably long, I chose to not include it right now.

I would be really grateful for any pointers, discussions, suggestions that would push us to the solution.

Thanks a lot and I am looking forward to the discussion!

Comment: Opinion based questions are not appropriate for StackOverflow

Comment: @JK.Hi! Yeah, I know now. I composed similar question to this, it got closed, I had some discussion on meta and learned (the hard way) on how to ask the questions and what is appropriate and what is not for SO. Sorry for asking this way in the first place, one would think after years of reading SO that he knows how it works. Obviously not. Learned my lesson, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered that treating `EventID` as another `Identifier` (e.g. "EID|1") would simplify the maintenance of your inverted index?

Using this PostgreSQL table as your base:

```
                 Table "public.matching"
    Column     |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 identifier    | text    |           | not null | 
 grouping_id   | integer |           | not null | 
 event_id_orig | integer |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "pk_matching" PRIMARY KEY, btree (identifier)
    "idx_matching_grouping_id" hash (grouping_id)
    "idx_matching_hash_pk" hash (identifier)
```

When a new record arrives, create the `identifier` set and add `EID|x` to the set, and run this:

```
with event_ident as (
  select 1 as event_id, unnest('{"EID|1","Cookie|A"}'::text[]) as identifier
), upd_crit as (
  select distinct m.grouping_id, min(m.grouping_id) over () as min_grouping_id
    from matching m
    join event_ident e on e.identifier = m.identifier
), upd_run as (
  update matching
     set grouping_id = upd_crit.min_grouping_id
    from upd_crit
   where upd_crit.grouping_id = matching.grouping_id
     and upd_crit.min_grouping_id != matching.grouping_id -- Added in response to comment
), insert_run as (
  insert into matching
    (identifier, grouping_id, event_id_orig)
  select e.identifier,
         coalesce(u.min_grouping_id, e.event_id) as grouping_id,
         e.event_id as event_id_orig
    from event_ident e
   cross join (select min(min_grouping_id) as min_grouping_id from upd_crit) u
  on conflict (identifier) do nothing
  returning *
)
select * from insert_run;
```

After your first four events, I have this:

```
=# select * from matching;
 identifier | grouping_id | event_id_orig 
------------+-------------+---------------
 EID|3      |           1 |             3
 EID|1      |           1 |             1
 Cookie|A   |           1 |             1
 EID|4      |           2 |             4
 EID|2      |           2 |             2
 Cookie|B   |           2 |             2
(6 rows)
```

After the round with email addresses:

```
=# select * from matching;
     identifier      | grouping_id | event_id_orig 
---------------------+-------------+---------------
 EID|5               |           1 |             5
 Email|a@example.com |           1 |             5
 EID|3               |           1 |             3
 EID|1               |           1 |             1
 Cookie|A            |           1 |             1
 EID|6               |           2 |             6
 Email|b@example.com |           2 |             6
 EID|4               |           2 |             4
 EID|2               |           2 |             2
 Cookie|B            |           2 |             2
(10 rows)
```

After `EventId` 7:

```
=# select * from matching;
     identifier      | grouping_id | event_id_orig 
---------------------+-------------+---------------
 EID|6               |           2 |             6
 Email|b@example.com |           2 |             6
 EID|4               |           2 |             4
 EID|2               |           2 |             2
 Cookie|B            |           2 |             2
 EID|7               |           1 |             7
 Phone|1234          |           1 |             7
 EID|5               |           1 |             5
 Email|a@example.com |           1 |             5
 EID|3               |           1 |             3
 EID|1               |           1 |             1
 Cookie|A            |           1 |             1
(12 rows)
```

And after adding your grand finale record:

```
=# select * from matching;
     identifier      | grouping_id | event_id_orig 
---------------------+-------------+---------------
 EID|8               |           1 |             8
 EID|6               |           1 |             6
 Email|b@example.com |           1 |             6
 EID|4               |           1 |             4
 EID|2               |           1 |             2
 Cookie|B            |           1 |             2
 EID|7               |           1 |             7
 Phone|1234          |           1 |             7
 EID|5               |           1 |             5
 Email|a@example.com |           1 |             5
 EID|3               |           1 |             3
 EID|1               |           1 |             1
 Cookie|A            |           1 |             1
(13 rows)
```

To retrieve in the format you used:

```
select grouping_id, 
       array_agg(distinct event_id_orig) as event_ids, 
       array_agg(identifier) filter (where identifier not like 'EID|%') as identifiers
  from matching
 group by grouping_id;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------
grouping_id | 1
event_ids   | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
identifiers | {Email|b@example.com,Cookie|B,Phone|1234,Email|a@example.com,Cookie|A}
```

Comment: I salute to you and your skills, dear sir. 

Like really, this solution is great! Thanks for sharing it with me.

I implemented your solution as BEFORE INSERT trigger on the table and changed one thing - added one more CTE for selecting records for update as `grouping_id != min_grouping_id`. This way when there is a huge entity with grouping_id already the same as min_grouping_id it wont try to update and saves some time. 

Once again - thanks a lot, really appreciate it!

Comment: @VojtěchKurka You do not need another CTE since that criterion can be added to the existing update (modified my answer, above). Also, for space efficiency in your inverted index, you should devise a strategy to shorten the keynames.

Comment: Regarding the update - that was my first solution. Then I benchmarked it and found out that the INDEX SCAN uses only equality operator that selects all rows and then it is using FILTER to get rid of those with same ID. With large entities the index matched for example 800k rows and removed 99.9% of them in filter, making it all slower.

Regarding the space - the text here was just for clarity. Otherwise I do MD5()::uuid on everything.